# Remove Blank List Item from StringBuilder Output w/out Losing Order

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple test app I am working on to teach myself some basic c# and xaml etc. The main idea is there are labels (questions) that a user answers by typing in some text in the textbox adjacent. In the example below I just made the labels (textblocks) say Label 1, Label 2... so on. On button click, two lists are created, one for textbox text and one for the entered text from the user. I then zip the list up and use stringbuilder to copy to clipboard for pasting somewhere else. As this is a zip of 2 lists I created a blank index in the textblock text list to keep the order of the list. This has created a blank space I am trying to remove (you can see how the third line is indented due to the blank list entry.

```
Label 1: Entered text from user
Label 2: Yes (enter some text below)
 Entered text from user
Label 3: Entered text from user
```

What is wanted:

```
Label 1: Entered text from user
Label 2: Yes (enter some text below)
Entered text from user
Label 3: Entered text from user
```

I have played with remove, trim, and other answers I researched to get the third line flush with the others but it either removes the line or gives unwanted output and just mangles things worse. Does anyone know an easy way to get the desired result below and or maybe I am making a simple thing more difficult than it needs to be and a better process to go about it? My main goal with this project was to practice being as dry as possible with the greatest amount of stringbuilder control.

XAML:

```xml
Title="MainWindow" Height="674" Width="581">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Grid x:Name="ControlGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="623" Margin="138,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="425">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Padding="0,8,0,0" Text="Label 1:"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="120,14,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="295"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="10,48,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Padding="0,8,0,0" Text="Label 2:"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Yes (enter some text below)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="65,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" GroupName="radio"/>
            <RadioButton Content="No (enter some text below)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="242,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="173" GroupName="radio"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="10,86,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="405"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="ThirdTB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="10,129,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Padding="0,8,0,0" Text="Label 3:"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="120,133,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="295"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestProj
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> labelTxt = new List<string>();
            List<string> dataTxt = new List<string>();
        
            foreach (TextBlock tbText in ControlGrid.Children.OfType<TextBlock>())
            {
                if (tbText.Name == "ThirdTB")
                {
                    labelTxt.Add("");
                }
                labelTxt.Add(tbText.Text);
            }

            var children = ControlGrid.Children.OfType<Control>();

            foreach (var input in children)
            {
                if ((input.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)) && (((TextBox)input).Text).Length > 0)
                {
                    dataTxt.Add(((TextBox)input).Text);
                }
                else if ((input.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton)) && (((RadioButton)input).IsChecked) == true)
                {
                    dataTxt.Add(((RadioButton)input).Content.ToString());
                }
            }

            var zipped = labelTxt.Zip(dataTxt.DefaultIfEmpty(), (l, t) => new { LabelText = l, Input = t });

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var lt in zipped)
            {
                if (lt.Input.Length > 0)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(lt.LabelText + " " + lt.Input);
                }
            }

            Clipboard.SetText(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two problems with your question: 1) the question doesn't seem to be _about_ WPF at all, nor actually need any WPF code in order to illustrate the question; 2) to the extent that the context in which you ran into the problem _is_ WPF, you are making things harder on yourself by not following proper MVVM practices, which means that your list-manipulation code is tangled up in your UI code. The latter issue is optional for you to solve, but please fix the question so that it removes the WPF-related aspects and presents it strictly with the `List<string>`/`StringBuilder` aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
        foreach (var lt in zipped)
        {
            if (lt.Input.Length > 0)
            {
                var finalText = (lt.LabelText + " " + lt.Input).Trim();
                sb.AppendLine(finalText);
            }
        }
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you, I never thought to assign the new string var and trim that way.